# I need to Search a Dynamic WebTable for a value then click on it using UFT

Tags: uft14, microfocus

I have a `WebTable` that will change in scope and size depending on what contracts are assigned to that user. It may have 1 contract or it may have 20 assigned them showing up in the `WebTable`. Using UFT my code would take a known contract (hard-coded) and look in the `webTable` for that contract then once found (if found) click on it. I have the code to iterate through the table and it populates the contract via `msgBox`, but I don't know how to click on it once found (`micclass` link).

```
set a = Browser("Browser").page("page").WebTable("innertext:=Table").Childitem(2, 2, "Link", 0)a.click
```

If I try to steal `msgBox` output I just get `"OBJECT NOT FOUND"` even if I create the object prior.

Answer (score 0):

If Browser("AOR_Main_Menu").Page("Welcome_Page").Link("11_Pending_Actions").Exist Then

'Looking through the table for a specific Contract and selecting it

'FIND OUT WHAT THIS LINE MEANS - DON'T NEED IT TO RUN BUT I WANT TO KNOW WHAT IT IS
'Browser("Browser").Page(“page").Check CheckPoint("Browser")

```
strDocumentNumber = "N4511217D8999"

Set oTable =       Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebTable("Search_Table")

Set oElement = Description.Create
oElement.Add "html tag","A"
oElement.add "innertext",strDocumentNumber

Set oElementCol = oTable.ChildObjects(oElement)

For i = 0 to oElementCol.Count-1

 oElementCol(i).click
```

I got this to work for me but can anyone tell me how this line works. 'DON'T NEED IT TO RUN BUT I WANT TO KNOW WHAT IT IS
'Browser("Browser").Page(“page").Check CheckPoint("Browser")
And maybe break this code down “barney style” so I can understand why this worked for me?